# Add effects such as fadeIn to slider into header

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I just want to add `fadeIn` when the photo is already changed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var num = 1;
  setInterval(function() {
    num += num + 1;

    if(num > 4) num=1;

    $('#nav').css('backgroundImage', 'url(photo'+num+'.png)');
  },4000);
});
```

Comment: Theres no fadeIn, nor any try to implement it

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to give effects of fadeIn and fadeOut.
This will change image at interval of 4 seconds.
To increase fadeIn and fadeOut time change intervals.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var num = 1;
        setInterval(function(){
            ++num;
            $("#demo").fadeOut(1500, function() {
                if(num == 4)
                    num = 1;
                $('#demo').css("background-image","url('photo"+num+".png')");
            }).fadeIn(1500);
        }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: Will it really work. If yes you are my code master XD